# Django manytomany field using a postgresql view

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am attempting to create a ManyToManyField in a model with a table in the database connected to a view in the database.

The model connected to the view (named precheck_check) migrated successfully so the only new code is `applicable_checks = models.ManyToManyFields(Check, related_name = '+')`.

When I try to migrate with the added code I get `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: referenced relation "precheck_check" is not a table"`

**Models.py**
    from **future** import unicode_literals

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import validate_slug,validate_comma_separated_integer_list
from static import validators


class Check(models.Model):
    pkey = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    cif = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    check_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False

# Create your models here.
class Job(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    jobID = models.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[validate_slug])
    original_file = models.FileField(upload_to='temp',validators = [validators.validate_zip])
    rev = models.IntegerField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = True)
    applicable_checks = models.ManyToManyField(Check, related_name = '+')


    def save(self):
        last_rev = Job.objects.filter(user_id=self.user_id).filter(jobID=self.jobID).order_by('-rev')
        if last_rev:
            self.rev = last_rev[0].rev + 1
        else:
            self.rev = 1
        super(Job,self).save()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.jobID + " rev " + str(self.rev)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['user','jobID']),
        ]
        unique_together = ("user","jobID","rev")
        ordering = ['-create_date']
        get_latest_by = 'create_date'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/mypebble/django-pgviews?